# Scheduled SMTP mail - not delivered - for Drupal 8

Tags: iis, drupal, smtp

I created an SMTP mail setup in my IIS for my Drupal 8 site. Mainly for sending emails for Creating account and Forgot password notifications.But I am always seeing "Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists" error. My SMTP config looks like below:

[image]

Domain name is same as my site name. Also my mailbox is not blocking this domain. Any help?!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the below values in php.ini file:

```
[mail function]

SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25


sendmail_from = from email id
```

after configuring this restart the iis.

note: check that you configure the right PHP version ini file.

You could refer below links for more detail:

http://drupal.org/node/261008

http://drupal.org/node/11570

http://drupal.org/node/279836